# Firestore query that finds a free time slot

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, schema, equivalent

I have a mysql query that finds free time slots in mysql and I need to do the same thing is Firestore. I have checked the internet but cannot find time slot query examples for Firestore. This is the MySQL query. Basically one table with datetimeStart and datetimeEnd. I do not see any changes happening on the firestore document. So what would be the equivalent in firestore on the server preferably?

```
  $freeSots = $db->raw()
        ->bind( ":today_start", $today_start )
        ->bind( ":today_end", $today_end )
        ->exec( "SELECT a.`interviewDateTimeEnd` AS free_after
                    FROM applicationForm a
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS
                    (
                       SELECT 1
                         FROM applicationForm b
                        WHERE b.`interviewDateTime` 
                      BETWEEN a.`interviewDateTimeEnd` 
                          AND a.`interviewDateTimeEnd` + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE
                    )
                    
         AND a.`interviewDateTimeEnd` BETWEEN :today_start AND :today_end 
         ORDER BY a.`interviewDateTimeEnd` DESC " )->fetchAll();
```

Comment: see [this answer](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=72&m=0)

Comment: hello @danblack thanks for your response but I already know how to do this is MySQL. What I need is how to do this is firestore.

Comment: I think that this only can be provided( if possible at all), when we will know how was created equivalent of `applicationForm` table in Firestore as there are no tables there...